# Android Java app fails to send selected file/data via Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth, file-transfer

My current android app can turn on Bluetooth, make itself discoverable, list paired devices, and select a file from the device ( ie an image). However when I attempted to hit "send" the app seems to crash with an error. Not sure if it's refusing to send, or if it's not actually obtaining the file (yesterday I had a problem where it refused to send the selected, saying for me to select a file repeatedly. I will post the crash results and my mainActivity code. If anyone suggestions or ideas, please let me know.

Error: Debugging device

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.bluetooth_demoproject, PID: 17593
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=300, data=null} to activity {com.example.bluetooth_demoproject/com.example.bluetooth_demoproject.MainActivity}: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_20161013-215137.png exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4107)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4150)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1517)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6120)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
               Caused by: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_20161013-215137.png exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
                  at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1799)
                  at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2346)
                  at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:832)
                  at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8909)
                  at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8894)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1517)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4224)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4507)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4475)
                  at com.example.bluetooth_demoproject.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:350)
                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6917)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4103)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4150) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1517) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6120) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
 Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8601', transport: 'socket'
```

Here is my MainActivity

```
package com.example.bluetooth_demoproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.bluetooth.BluetoothA2dp;
 import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Set;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  // Creating objects -----------------------------
   private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 0;
    private static final int REQUEST_BLU = 1;
  //  private static final int REQUEST_DISCOVER_BT_ = 1;
   private static int CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID = 0;
ListView dialog_ListView;
TextView mBluetoothStatus, mPairedDevicesList, mTextFolder;
ImageView mBluetoothIcon;
Button mOnButton, mDiscoverableButton, mPairedDevices, mbuttonOpenDialog, msendBluetooth, mbuttonUp;
File root, fileroot, curFolder;
EditText dataPath;
private static final int DISCOVER_DURATION = 300;
private List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
// -------------------------------------------------------
BluetoothAdapter mBlueAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    dataPath =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.FilePath);


    mTextFolder = findViewById(R.id.folder);
    mBluetoothStatus = findViewById(R.id.BluetoothStatus);
    mBluetoothIcon = findViewById(R.id.bluetoothIcon);
    mOnButton = findViewById(R.id.onButton);
  //  mOffButton = findViewById(R.id.offButton);
    mDiscoverableButton = findViewById(R.id.discoverableButton);
    mPairedDevices = findViewById(R.id.pairedDevices);
    mPairedDevicesList = findViewById(R.id.pairedDeviceList);
    mbuttonOpenDialog = findViewById(R.id.opendailog);
    msendBluetooth = findViewById(R.id.sendBluetooth);
    mbuttonUp = findViewById(R.id.up);

    mbuttonOpenDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dataPath.setText("");
            showDialog(CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

    root = new 
    File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    curFolder = root;
    msendBluetooth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendViaBluetooth();
        }
      });


    //adapter
    mBlueAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    if(mBlueAdapter == null){
        mBluetoothStatus.setText("Bluetooth is not available");
        return;
    }
    else {
        mBluetoothStatus.setText("Bluetooth is available");
    }
    //if Bluetooth isnt enabled, enable it
    if (!mBlueAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new
                Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }
        //set image according to bluetooth Status
    if (mBlueAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        mBluetoothIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.action_on);
    }
    else {
        mBluetoothIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.action_off);
    }


    //on button Click
    mOnButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!mBlueAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                showToast("Turning Bluetooth on...");
                // intent to on bluetooth
                Intent intent = new 
    Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);

            }
            else {
                showToast("Bluetooth is already on");
            }

        }
      });

    //discover Bluetooth button
    mDiscoverableButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            if (!mBlueAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                showToast("Making device discoverable");
                Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_BLU);
            }

        }

     });

    // off button click
  //  mOffButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  //      @Override
  //      public void onClick(View v) {
  //          if (mBlueAdapter.isEnabled()) {
   //             showToast("Turning Bluetooth off...");
   //             // intent to turn off bluetooth
   //             mBluetoothIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.action_off);
       //         }
     //          else{
      //             showToast("Bluetooth is already off");
        //        }
         //
         //    }
            //});


    //get paired device button click
    mPairedDevices.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mBlueAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                mPairedDevices.setText("Paired Devices");
                Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = mBlueAdapter.getBondedDevices();
                for (BluetoothDevice device : devices){
                    mPairedDevices.append("\nDevice: " + device.getName() + "," + device );

                }
            }
            else {
                //bluetooth is off and cant get paired devices
                showToast("Turn on bluetooth to get paired devices");
            }

        }
       });




}

   //  @Override
   // protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
 //     super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);
 //      switch (id) {
  //         case CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID:
     //             ListDir(curFolder);
//            break;
//    }
// }

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog dialog = null;
    if (id == CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID) {
        dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dailoglayout);
        dialog.setTitle("Select Files");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        mTextFolder = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.folder);
        mbuttonUp = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.up);
        mbuttonUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                     ListDir(curFolder.getParentFile());
            }
        });

        dialog_ListView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialoglist);
        dialog_ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                File selected = new File(fileList.get(position));
                if (selected.isDirectory()) {
                    ListDir(selected);
                }
                else if (selected.isFile()) {
                    getSelectedFile(selected);
                }
                else {
                    dismissDialog(CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID);
                }
            }
        });

    }
    return dialog;
}


 @Override
 protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);
    if (id == CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID) {
          ListDir(curFolder);
    }
}









public void getSelectedFile(File f) {
    dataPath.setText(f.getAbsolutePath());
    fileList.clear();
    dismissDialog(CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID);
}

public void ListDir(File f) {
    if (f.equals(root)) {
        mbuttonUp.setEnabled(false);
    }
    else {
        mbuttonUp.setEnabled(true);
    }
    curFolder = f;
    mTextFolder.setText(f.getAbsolutePath());
    dataPath.setText(f.getAbsolutePath());
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    fileList.clear();

    for (File file : files) {
        fileList.add(file.getPath());
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> directoryList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fileList);
    dialog_ListView.setAdapter(directoryList);

}

// exits to app --------------------------------
public void exit(View V) {
    mBlueAdapter.disable();
    Toast.makeText(this, "*** Now bluetooth is off...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();
}

// send file via bluetooth ------------------------
public void sendViaBluetooth() {
    if(!dataPath.equals(null)) {
        if(mBlueAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Device doesnt support bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
           enableBluetooth();
        }

    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "please select a file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


public void enableBluetooth() {
    showToast("Making device discoverable");
    Intent discoveryIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    discoveryIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, DISCOVER_DURATION);
    startActivityForResult(discoveryIntent, REQUEST_BLU);
}




@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == DISCOVER_DURATION && requestCode == REQUEST_BLU) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);// STOPPED HERE-----------------------------------------------------------------
        i.setType("*/*");
        File file = new File(dataPath.getText().toString());
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));

        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
        if (list.size() > 0) {
            String packageName = null;
            String className = null;
            boolean found = false;

            for (ResolveInfo info : list) {
                packageName = info.activityInfo.packageName;
                if (packageName.equals("com.android.bluetooth")) {
                    className = info.activityInfo.name;
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            //CHECK BLUETOOTH available or not------------------------------------------------
            if (!found) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth not been found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                i.setClassName(packageName, className);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}




@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
 //   if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
       // Toast.makeText(this, "**********************************\nDeveloper: www.santoshkumarsingh.com\n**********************************", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   //     return true;
   // }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

//toast message function
private void showToast(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();
}

 }
```

Comment: After removing:  //CHECK BLUETOOTH available or not------------------------------------------------
               // if (!found) {
               //     Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth not been found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               // } else {
               //     i.setClassName(packageName, className);
               //     startActivity(i);    }
              The app no longer crashes when pushing send, however it is unable to send the data

Answer (score 0):

You have trouble with file exchange not with BLE.

Did you ever read [Android FileUriExposedException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException)?